# Play framework: how to serialize/deserialize from/to JSON in Scala

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

In java I used jackson and Gson with annotations, is there something similar in Play? It forces me to create another object like this in addition to my classes:

```
  implicit val payloadRead : Reads[payload] = (
      (JsPath \ "act").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "sk").read[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "uid").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "ft").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "lt").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "em").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "nts").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "ugr").read[Int]
  )  (payload.apply _)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Play does provide macros to generate the above for you, eg:

```
implicit val payloadRead = Json.reads[payload]
```

See [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJsonInception) for documentation.

That said, one of the nice features of Play's json support is it's explicit.  You can very easily combine and reuse parsers in a much more flexible way than you can with Jackson.  With Jackson, you don't really know what it's doing, it's doing a lot of reflection to access your class which is completely opaque to you.  In contrast, there is no reflection used in Play's json support, so you have complete control.